# Execute two buttons with single click

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have a simple C # application that contains buttons and a web browser, each button execute a request and displays the result of the request on the web browser. And use the results of a request in the next button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1") != null)
            {
            HtmlElement txt1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1");
            txt1.SetAttribute("value", "test");
            webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
            }
        }
```

Is there any method or way to perform the two buttons with a single click, but the second button, do not execute until the web browser is loaded.

in the first button, I added

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted + = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
```

but the second button  excuted several times, so I added in the last line of the button 2:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted - = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
```

it works, but in the console I find that Button 2 is execute twice

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JMK: I think the problem here is not executing both methods after each other, but rather delaying the second call until the navigation has completed

Comment: @Nuffin Sorry you are correct, the WebBrowser object has a loaded event I believe which you can subscribe to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an event that will call the code once the document has completed loading.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}    

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: first piece of code will most likely fail as WebBrowser might not finish loading page before button2_Click tries to access it. The second one is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I realised there would be a problem with the first snippet when I read what button2 did, hence I added the second. I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't think like executing second button click. There is  [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event which you must listen to and execute neccesary code afterwards.

Comment: thank you David Goshadze
it is what I did in the first button, I added
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted + = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
  but the second excute button several times, so I added in the last line of the button 2:
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted - = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
it works, but in the console I find that Button 2 is execute twice

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => {button2_Click(sender, e);};
  button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

will register the button2_Click method to be executed after the document is loaded completely as triggered by button1_Click().

Answer (score 1):

You could make the following call from your button1_click method.

```
button2_Click(sender, e);
```

Comment: That would execute the button right away instead of after loading the second page.

Answer (score -3):

You could give an argument in the url:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.test.com?excuteSecondButton=Yes");
```

Then on the second page you check if that argument was given:

```
PageLoad()
{
  if(Request.QueryString["executeSecondButton"].Equals("Yes"))
  {
    button2_Click(button2, new RoutedEventArgs());
  }
}
```

Comment: when would you execute `Request.QueryString["executeSecondButton"].Equals("Yes");`?