# Execute buttons with one click

Tags: c#, .net, button, click, browser

I have a simple C # application that contains buttons and a web browser, each button execute a request and displays the result of the request on the web browser. And I use the results of a request in the next button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1") != null)
            {
            HtmlElement txt1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1");
            txt1.SetAttribute("value", "test");
            webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
            }
        }
```

my question is to find method or way to perform the two buttons with a single click, but the second button, do not execute until the web browser is loaded.
in my first solution, I added in the first button :

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted + = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
```

but the second button excuted several times, so I added in the last line of the button 2:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted - = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
```

it works, but in the console I find that Button 2 is execute twice

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of [Execute two buttons with single click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958655/execute-two-buttons-with-single-click) - didn't those answers given to your first question help you?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958655/execute-two-buttons-with-single-click

Comment: no :( , I add the DocumentCompleted but each button execute rwice or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approaching this issue the wrong way. First *you are not looking* for a way to click two buttons. You are looking for a way to click one button and execute an operation if a condition is met.

Basically you just need to call `button2.PerformClick()` in your WebBrowser `DocumentCompleted` method. If however you want to ensure that button1 was clicked, you can set a bool in button1 Click method and reset it in the button2 Click method.

If you need to perform more than one button click in your document complete method after the first button click, you can add them to your `DocumentCompleted` method like this:

First subscribe normally.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += Document_Completed;
```

Normally you can generate the method stub by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> after subscribing to the event. The method could be as follows:

```
private void Document_Completed(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //here you add the other buttons that must be clicked when document complete
     button1.PerformClick(); button2.PerformClick();//etc
     //you could even iterate all over the buttons on the form and click each of them if it meets a certain condtition.
}
```

I hope that answers your question :)

Comment: thank you for your help, i have already try the "button2.PerformClick()"in the WebBrowser DocumentCompleted method, it worked if I have juste two buttons, but if I have 3 or more buttons, DocumentCompleted method will not be the solution because  I need to click just  on the first button, and the other buttons cliked automatiquely one by one

Comment: so i add in the last line of the methode buttonX_Click :
 `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(button(X+1)_Click);`
and in the first line of the methode buttonX+1_Click I add :
`webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(button(X+1)_Click);`
is that correct?

Comment: No, if you need to click more than one button, do all the Clicking in the DocumentCompleted method. I'll update my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentCompleted  is executed each time your WebBrowser control finishes downloading a document.

You only need to subscribe once.

Comment: what you mean by subscribe once? in the first declaration of DocumentCompleted ,I did "+=" to create listener but in the second declaration i did "-=" to stop the listener